# Chinese characters in SharePoint content DB

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-database

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and having a problem and I found some records in UserData table that seem to have Chinese characters in the column. The column where I see this is the tp_ColumnSet.  This column is XML of the values in the list that it belongs to.  I have found this list in SharePoint by using the tp_ListId and looking up in AllLists the list that matches that ID.

Here is the XML for this record.

```
<float1>1.200000000000000e+001</float1>
<float2>2.000000000000000e+002</float2>
<float3>3.000000000000000e+002</float3>
<float4>4.000000000000000e+002</float4>
<int1>497</int1>
<int2>2</int2>
<int3>497</int3>
<int5>31</int5>
<ntext2>&lt;div class="ExternalClass9DB19E6929B74D6EB9D92825BBE42503"&gt;&lt;p&gt;​ESTA ES UNA PRUEBA&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</ntext2>
<nvarchar1>TICKET DE PRUEBA</nvarchar1>
<nvarchar3>(3) Baja</nvarchar3>
<nvarchar4>Iniciada</nvarchar4>
<nvarchar8>醩㹈䒂伷垎짞蜑</nvarchar8>
<nvarchar9>﷚ꭶ♛䭬墶✄弆럒</nvarchar9>
<nvarchar10>໇橉桸䒦嚌ᤙ䀰銫</nvarchar10>
<nvarchar11>蘄톾䣡蚀粚智棩</nvarchar11>
```

Google translate doesn't seem to understand these characters.  I picked several different languages but none of it makes much sense.  We don't have any Chinese, Korean, or Japanese language packs installed, so I don't know why this content is in there like that.
Does anyone know what this says, or why it is in there?  Has my SharePoint been compromised?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

They're encoded characters. What you're seeing is expected behavior, in addition, outside of a lab/test environment, you shouldn't be poking in the database and should never query SharePoint databases directly as that is not supported.